# Rewrite lambda function as regular function

Tags: python

I am learning about lambda expressions and I am trying to rewrite this lambda expression as a regular one

```
df['my_col_score'] = df.apply(lambda x: col_score(x['other_col'], string_const), axis = 1)
```

here is my attempt

```
def the_func(df, col, string_const):
    for x in col:
        df.apply(col_score(col['other_col], axis=1))
```

this is not correct though and I am unsure where I went wrong

Comment: Ok, great! What's your question? [ask]

Comment: Why do you call `df.apply` in `the_func` and not `col_score`?

Comment: A lambda function is an anonymous function. It cannot and should not be replaced in this scenario. You are passing it as an argument to df.apply().

Comment: @SPARTACUS5329 every lambda expression is replaceable by a regular function definition statement. Whether you *should* is mostly a matter of style.

Comment: For a given function created by `lambda <args>: <expression>` it can be trivially implemented using a function definition statement `def function (<args>): return <expression>`, i dont know why you think you had to add a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever your function is you can apply it by using apply and lambda. Following is an example:

```
def loaded_items(tokens):
    return col_score(col['other_col'], axis=1)
        
df['my_col_score'] = df['tokens'].apply(lambda x: loaded_items(x))
```

Since you haven't provided much information about your functions and their objectives, this answer might be imprecise.
But anyway, I hope it helps.